# React Native global back handling

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have 3 components:

1. ComponentA
2. ComponentB
3. BackPressHandlingComponent

`BackPressHandlingComponent` deals with back press.

When back pressed from ComponentA; I must exit the app.

When back pressed from ComponentB; I must go to ComponentA.

Here is my BackPressHandlingComponent code -

```
import { BackHandler } from 'react-native';

export class BackPressHandlingComponent extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.handleBackPress);
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.handleBackPress);
    }
}
```

My question is -

How do I tell BackPressHandlingComponent from Component A that I must exit app and from Component B that I need to go back to Component A

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your use case, I would have added`Backpress event listeners` on ComponentA and ComponentB, such that when you are on ComponentA when the callback is called you can exit the app and when in ComponentB its callback is called you can navigate to ComponentA.

Simple demo for above solution:

**App.js**

```
/**
 *
 * @format
 * @flow
 */

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View, TouchableOpacity, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import ComponentA from './ComponentA'
import ComponentB from './ComponentB'
import BackHandlerHOC from './BackHandlerHOC'

type Props = {};
export default class App extends Component<Props> {
  state = {
    render: 'A'
  }

  toggleComponent = () => {
    let component = 'A'
    if (this.state.render === 'A') {
      component = 'B'
    }
    this.setState({ render: component })
  }

  render() {
    const { render } = this.state
    const wrappercomponent = render === 'A' ? (
      <BackHandlerHOC
        name="ComponentA"
        Component={ComponentA}
      />
    ) : (
        <BackHandlerHOC
          name="ComponentB"
          Component={ComponentB}
        />
      )
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={() => this.toggleComponent()}
        >
          <Text> Change </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        {wrappercomponent}
      </View>
    )
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    padding: 20
  }
})
```

**ComponentA**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';

class ComponentA extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>A</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default ComponentA;
```

**ComponentB**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';

class ComponentB extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>B</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default ComponentB;
```

**BackHandlerHOC**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BackHandler, ToastAndroid, View, Text } from 'react-native';

class BackHandlerHOC extends Component {
  componentDidMount = () => {
    BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.backPressHandler);
  };

  componentWillUnmount = () => {
    BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.backPressHandler);
  };

  backPressHandler = () => {
    const { name } = this.props;
    if (name === 'ComponentA') {
      BackHandler.exitApp()
    } else {
      // this.props.navigator.resetTo({
      //   screen: 'ComponentA'
      // })
      ToastAndroid.show('will go back to A', 0);
    }
    return true;
  };

  render() {
    const { Component } = this.props;
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>Hello from backpress</Text>
      <Component />
    </View>
);
  }
}

export default BackHandlerHOC;
```

You can also find the working example on expo [here](https://snack.expo.io/@warl0ck/backhandler-hoc)

Hope this helps

Comment: I want to handle this globally not in each component

Comment: in that case you can create an HOC component which will listen to Backpress like you `backpressComponent` and in that you will need to knwo which component is currently active and handle accordingly. Ill update the answer accordingly.

Comment: Ok thank you :) Let me know when you update your answer

Comment: @Julia, I have updated the answer, as per your requirements, almost forgot about it, that why the delay.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add another approach,
I made use of the `react-navigation` lifecycle events,and the `hardwareBackPress` event, mind you the version of `react-navigation` here is `3.x.x`.

The lifecycle event `onWillFocus` is called when the screen comes in view and the life-cycle event `onWillBlur` is called when the user is moving on to another screen, here somehow the React lifecycle events are in the hands of `react-navigation`, hence cannot use them here see [https://reactnavigation.org/docs/3.x/navigation-lifecycle.](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/3.x/navigation-lifecycle)

Following is the code:

```
import { BackHandler,Alert } from "react-native";
import { NavigationEvents } from 'react-navigation';
class SomeComponent {
             //...my componentDidMount etc and other methods..... 

   backButtonAction(){
            Alert.alert(
            "Confirm Exit",
            "Do you want to exit the app?",
            [
              {
                text: "No",
                onPress: () => {},
                style: "cancel"
              },
              { text: "Yes", onPress: () => BackHandler.exitApp() }
            ],
            { cancelable: false }
          );
          return true; // coz the event handler needs to return boolean.
        };  
  setBackButtonAction(){
        BackHandler.addEventListener(
                        "hardwareBackPress",
                        this.backButtonAction
                      );
  }
  removeBackButtonAction(){
        BackHandler.removeEventListener(
                      "hardwareBackPress",
                      this.backButtonAction
                    );
  }
  render() {
                    return (
                          <Container>
                            <NavigationEvents
                            onWillFocus={payload => this.setBackButtonAction()}
                            onWillBlur={payload => this.removeBackButtonAction()}
                            /> //..... my view code
                          </Container>)
          }
    }
```